# Can I change my default language from English to German?

Tags: magento2, localisation, language

Can you provide a guide for changing store language from English to German?

> Module i18n only has en_Us file.

I have learned a user guide, but cannot understand that.

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

there is an inofficial language pack for de from splendid: https://github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE

I did not test it yet but we will try it as a base for a new project

Answer (score 1):

There are no official translations available yet for Magento 2, most likely they will be added within the nearest releases (that's why selecting custom locale does not change language). The only option for now is to [create your own language package](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#m2devgde-xlate-languagepack).

Comment: how to get csv file for magento 2 german language ?

Comment: It is not yet available, you can only create your own translation for now.

Comment: ok. and for that i run any command ? or put individual csv file put in module ?

Comment: Take a look at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html